# How to build an iterative form of multiple recursive calls?

Tags: recursion, iteration, computer-science, dynamic-programming

For an assignment on dynamic programming, we need to give an iterative implementation for a recursive formula.

To keep it simple: let's say that in all iterations, either `a`or `b` hold, if not we're in the base-clause.

We have a formula like:

```
f(x){
   if(x.a && !x.b):
     return f(option_1)
   else if(x.b && !x.a):
     return f(option_2)
   else if(x.a && x.b):
     f_1 = f(option_1)
     f_2 = f(option_2)
     return betterOption(f_1,f_2)
   else:
     return base_clause
```

How do I compute this iteratively? I get stuck on the option where both a & b hold, because we need to compute both options. Using recursion in any form is not allowed here.

Comment: Why isn't `x` used in the function? Are `a`,`b`,`option_1` and `option_2` static? Does `betterOption` call `f` again?

Comment: Ah yes, that was kind of vague. This was just meant to illustrate the problem, not the problem itself. Assume a and/or b are properties of x. betterOption would make the choice between option_1 and option_2, as one choice is needed. That's totally besides the point though, as I just wanted to know how this would work iteratively.

Comment: "*That's totally besides the point*". No, because depending on the type of the recursive algorithm the iterative one can vary.

Comment: When you say "*`betterOption` would make the choice between `option_1` and `option_2`*", does it mean it is like a base clause or it calls `f` again? And do `option_1` and `option_2` depend on `x`?